# Logitech Revue GoogleTv DDMS Screenshot not working

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot, google-tv, ddms

Can anyone take screenshots of their Logitech Revue?

Using Ethernet connected computer and GoogleTV (logitech revue, firmware version 3.2) I can successfully see the device in Eclipse after:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.132:5555
```

But when I try to get a screenshot I get screen not available as shown here:

[image: Screen Not Available Error]

Before it says "Screen not available" it says "Capturing..." for about 55 seconds.  I am using ADT 20.02.

I originally was trying over WiFi and thought maybe Ethernet would help.  It does not.

One alternative I have considered is that perhaps an emulator will allow screenshots.  I am on Windows and it appears the GoogleTV addon for emulation is not compatible:

[image]

I am wondering if anyone can get screenshots of their Logitech Revue with DDMS or if anyone is using an alternative method I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: I still have not received an answer, but I have a couple of updates.  I got a Vizio Co-Star and was able to get a screenshot over wifi with the same technique and laptop from the original quesiton.  It took >45 and <55 seconds.  When live TV was on the screenshot is all black (that's ok), otherwise I could see my app.  I also heard from GoogleTV team that they have heard of this issue on Revue's they made it sound like I might have a bad revue.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, I am able to take screenshots of my Logitech Revue using the DDMS plugin in Eclipse (like your screenshots show). There's no need to have the "Google TV Addon" installed - it just works.

Comment: What Android version is your Logitech Revue running, would you be willing to show a screenshot like mine with the screenshot working?

Comment: Hmm, is your DDMS computer and GoogleTV connected by WiFi or Ethernet?

Comment: Both Wifi - but I doubt it should matter. TCP is TCP. Btw, is the logcat working?

Comment: yes, deploying apps works and logcat works, can you tell me how long it takes to display the screen capture and what resolution TV you are using?  I am using a 720P (1366 x 768) TV.

Comment: 720p. It does take about 6 seconds, but in my experience that's "normal." From a quick wireshark dump, it appears that the image is transferred via the same connection the logcat data is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18838/discussion-between-mark-scheel-and-yydl)

Comment: yydl - if you have any ideas how I could debug using wireshark please let me know.  I tried going to a different house with different tv and network and still see same problem, a fail after 55 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Taking screenshots with DDMS works fine for Google TV apps. You cannot take screenshots of video.

ADB can get stuck in a bad mode, so its best to stop it with:

```
adb kill-server
```

and the restart it:

```
adb start-server
```

Then add your device back again:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.132
```

and confirm that it is connected:

```
adb devices
```

Comment: Good point about video but I am indeed trying to take screenshots of an app (no video).  I can not confirm that I am connected by your method, perhaps this is a clue as to why things are not working?  This is what your commands look like:

c:\>adb kill-server

c:\>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

c:\>adb connect 192.168.1.115:5555
connected to 192.168.1.115:5555

c:\>adb devices
List of devices attached


c:\>

Comment: Disregard above comment, that is what happens when you do not have the right IP in Settings > Applications > Development for remote debugging.  It thinks you are connected but then drops it.  Fixed and now I can see the device using adb devices, and in DDMS but always get a "screen not available" message in the Device Screen Capture tool.

Comment: Have you tried to restart Eclipse; it also gets into bad states some times. Otherwise it could be a networking issue. I would highly recommend having your Google TV device wired.

Comment: I tried restarting eclipse and no behavior change.  I even tried a different house with different TV and network set up (but wifi only in second location). Still same issue as detailed in original question.